# PyMongo Cursor to List Fastest Way Possible

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

After running some tests (casting a PyMongo set to a list vs iterating over the cursor and saving to a list) I've noticed that the step from cursor to data in memory is negligible. For a db cursor of about 160k records, it averages about 2.3s.

Is there anyway to make this conversion from document to object faster? Or will I have to choose between casting to a list and iterating over the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

After some A/B testing, it seems like there isn't really a way to speed this up, unless you change your Python interpreter. Alternatively, bulk pulling from the DB could speed this up.